# jquery ui dialog box not loading form tags in first ajax request

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi i am using Jquery UI dialog for editing a content also adding jquery ui tabs in dialog, when you click on edit button it sends an ajax request get form with data filled in it.

But in first ajax request when dialog open it not adding form tags its just showing form elements i can not submit form at all. i have to close dialog and open it again it works proper html has form tags in too.

in console output first request showing form tags are there. but in dialog box nothing.

here is my code

```
$(".edit-media").on('click', function () {
    var url = $(this).data('url') + '?' + Math.random();
    // $("#media_edit_dialog").load(url);
    $.post(url, function (data) {
        $("#media_edit_dialog").html('').html(data)
            .dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            open: function () {
                console.log('i will open');
                $('#tabs, .tabs').tabs();
                Admin.dateTimePicker();
            },
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    $("#media_edit_form").submit();
                },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        })
            .dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate it before, and on ajax just call

```
jQuery('#media_edit_dialog').dialog('open');
```

Keep property auto open set to false

Comment: great it works like charm just add to load html data jQuery('#media_edit_dialog').html(data).dialog('open');